# Draw this shape

Tags: c++, opengl

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
// color of the shape
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
// draw shape
glVertex2f(50, 200);
glVertex2f(50, 170);
glVertex2f(80, 200);
glVertex2f(80, 240);
glVertex2f(50, 240);
glEnd();
```

I am struggling to draw the shape below. My shape just needs to be rotated.

Preview:

[image]

How the shapes should look like:

[image]

Comment: Note that the axes of the default OpenGL coordinate system go from left to right and from bottom to top. This is likely to be the only "issue" with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primitive type [`GL_POLYGON`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) concatenates the vertex coordinates to a convex polygon. The last point is concatenated to the first point. For a shape with 4 corner points, 4 vertex coordinates are sufficient:

```
                    + (80, 240)
                  / |
Y                /  |
^               /   |
|   (50, 200) +     |
|             |     |
|             |     |
|             |     |
|   (50, 170) +-----+ (80, 170)
|
+-------------> X
```

```cpp
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex2f(50, 170);
glVertex2f(80, 170);
glVertex2f(80, 240);
glVertex2f(50, 200);
glEnd();
```